# How can I get more precise regression tree?

Tags: multiple-regression, random-forest, cart

I am a complete newbie to regression trees so maybe I am not understanding it properly. I got the following tree from my analysis (function [tree()](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/tree/docs/tree) from R package `tree`):

[image]

This is nice, but how can I get more precise tree? For example, the clc_312 variable could definitely be split at more thresholds, giving more precise model. This is obvious when I plot the clc_312 variable against the response variable:

[image]

This plot shows the clc_312 variable cut in 10 pools and boxploted (don't know how to analyze this better, scatterplott is just a mess, you don't actually see the distribution of the response variable for particular range of clc_312 values). The green thing are means with CI, red line corresponds to the threshold detected by `tree()`. The range could definitely be split more.

First I thought that `tree()` will only split each variable once, but I did the following experiment on generated data, which shows that one variable can actually be split more times:

```
require(tree)

set.seed(123)
N <- 100
x <- runif(N, 0, 10)
alpha <- -2
beta1 <- 0.5
beta2 <- 0.1
sigma <- 0.005
y <- alpha + beta1 * x + rnorm(N, 0, sigma)

tree1 <- tree(y ~ x)
plot(tree1, type = "u")
text(tree1)
```

[image]

So it *is* possible! How do I force `tree()` to give me more precise model and continue to split the variables further?

Answer (score 3):

You simply can't get high precision from a single tree unless your sample size is enormous and the signal:noise ratio is high.  Suppose that a predictor X acts linearly against Y.  Many splits will be needed to represent this relationship, but the catch is that the estimate of $E(Y|X)$ for each interval of $X$ makes no use of the estimate of $E(Y|X)$ in the surrounding $X$ intervals.  In other words, single trees do not use interpolation or borrowing of information across $X$.  Because of that the variance of the estimate of $E(Y|X)$ is high and the tree does not compete with smooth methods such as ordinary regression or regression splines.  Plotting the tree's predicted values against $X$ starts to reveal the problem.

Comment: 1) *"Suppose that a predictor X acts linearly against Y"* this is not true! This is the reason I use the tree - because glm has problems with this dataset. Independent variables are pretty much linearly dependent (as they are habitat areas which always sum up to the area of 100 m circle).

Comment: 2) *"You simply can't get high precision from a single tree unless..."* Your answer confuses me. What do you say to the answer of @user3969377? It seems that this way I *can* actually get higher precision?

Comment: Please try to understand my answers, and respond with single comment entries.  For a method to be competitive, it must perform well in simple situations where we know the truth, such as linear models.  Trees don't perform well in that situation.  Then consider smooth relaxation of the linearity assumption using for example regression splines.  Regression methods can flexibly fit nonlinear relationships with high precision (low variance); single trees cannot.  And the answer from @user3969377 has to do with bias but not with variance; minimize bias by using a tiny bucket size but ruin precision

Comment: Frank, thank you! The data is so crazy that smooth methods can actually perform worse - for datasets like mine, random forests are usually used. What do you think of the random forests - do they still have this problem? All I need is a predictive power (I don't need to know which variable is significant)

Comment: Random forests will almost always beat single trees, but you lose all interpretability advantages of a tree.  Flexible regression (possible with penalization) is likely to be very competitive with RF and more interpretable depending on dimensionality.  But it is *not* the case that smooth methods perform worse with noisy data.

Comment: Frank, if the question was getting more accuracy on a classification tree, instead of regression tree, how does your comment(s) change?  And, can any data set be converted to classification by setting bounds?

Comment: If the precision of a prediction is not adequate, the precision of a classification is even more problematic.  Classification is a minimum information/maximum variance approach to the problem.  Think of binary classification as providing one bit of information, which is the minimum amount of information you can have other than no information at all.  You never help with a problem by discarding information; you only make the problem *seem* to be simpler.

Answer (score 1):

From ?tree.control there is information on how to get more depth to the tree.

```
To produce a tree that fits the data perfectly, set mindev = 0 and minsize = 2, 
if the limit on tree depth allows such a tree.
```

As an illustration of how to use the tree control variable

```
library(tree)
data(mtcars)
c1 <- tree(mpg ~., data=mtcars)
plot(c1,type="uniform"); text(c1)
c2 <- tree(mpg ~., data=mtcars, 
           control=tree.control(nobs=nrow(mtcars),mindev = 0, minsize = 2))
plot(c2,type="uniform"); text(c2)
```

As Frank Harrell correctly points out, more depth does not correspond to more precision, and results should be checked by predicting values, preferably on data that wasn't used to construct the tree.
Ref: http://plantecology.syr.edu/fridley/bio793/cart.html

In the car example, it does appear that a deeper tree can give better results on a blind test data set, illustrated in the following example...

```
library(tree)
library(caret)
data(mtcars)

## 75% of the sample size
smp_size <- floor(0.75 * nrow(mtcars))

## set the seed to make your partition reproductible
set.seed(123)
train_ind <- sample(seq_len(nrow(mtcars)), size = smp_size)

train <- mtcars[train_ind, ]
test <- mtcars[-train_ind, ]

car_tree_mdl_1 <- tree(mpg ~., data=train)
plot(car_tree_mdl_1); text(car_tree_mdl_1)

car_tree_mdl_2 <- tree(mpg ~., data=train, 
           control=tree.control(nobs=nrow(mtcars),mindev = 0, minsize = 2))
plot(car_tree_mdl_2,type="uniform"); text(car_tree_mdl_2)

pred_mdl_1 <- predict(car_tree_mdl_1, newdata=test)
pred_mdl_2 <- predict(car_tree_mdl_2, newdata=test)

cmp<-data.frame(mpg=test$mpg, tree_1=pred_mdl_1, tree_2=pred_mdl_2)
    cmp.err<-data.frame(tree_1_err=(cmp$tree_1-cmp$mpg)/cmp$mpg, 
                    tree_2_err=(cmp$tree_2-cmp$mpg)/cmp$mpg)*100
rownames(cmp.err)<-rownames(cmp)
colors=c("darkblue", "red", "green")
barplot(as.matrix(t(cmp)), beside=TRUE, col=colors )
legend("top", legend=c("data","tree","deep tree"), fill=colors)
cat("Comparison between data, tree 1, and tree 2\n")
cmp
cat("Comparison of percent error between tree 1 and tree 2\n")
cmp.err
```

Comment: This seems like part of an answer, at most. Would you mind expanding it?

Comment: @gung If you think the help file for tree.control is incomplete or unclear you should inform the maintainer of tree.

Comment: Thanks! Argument `minsize` doesn't change anything (could stay = 10), but the mindev is the key one! Lowering it to 0.003 gives much better tree. PS: seems that authors of `tree()` function found a new way how to hide parameters of a function from users...

Comment: I'm noob too, and am challenged by the help files also.

Comment: If I remember correctly, minsize affects how many observations can be at a node, while mindev is the minimum standard deviation of the split.