# Can you use a decision tree to predict a numeric variable? Is a decision tree that predicts a numerical variable a regression tree?

Tags: cart, continuous-data

I am pretty sure that decision trees are only used to classify categorical variables. But I was wondering if there was a way for one to predict a numeric variable? If there is ... what is the method predicting this different data type. Is it just the method used for a regression tree? Are they one and the same?

Comment: **Yes**, you certainly can do so. They are called regression trees, search this site. For an example see https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/122168/how-can-i-get-more-precise-regression-tree   and  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/317412/machine-learning-methods-for-exploring-relationships-for-a-continuous-response-v

Comment: I could understand someone thinking "_decision_ tree" implies a categorical target, but the "decision" refers to the splitting nodes.  From the leading paragraph of [the wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decision_tree_learning): "Decision trees where the target variable can take continuous values (typically real numbers) are called regression trees."